# Hover Clip not Working

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to use CSS to clip a figure to 20px and then show the full figure when I hover over it. However the clip region does not change when I hover over it.

My CSS looks like this:

```
#map figure {
    background-color: rgb(70,76,222);
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    clip: rect(0px, 20px, 20px, 0px);
}

figure:hover {
    clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 0px);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The HTML Looks like

```
<figure id="point1">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption>
       <time>5:30 a.m.</time> Stop at Mills Moraine for a 
       view of the sunrise.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Can you tell me why the clip rectangle doesn't change on hover?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the selector `#map figure` is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the selector `figure:hover`. You need to increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the second selector in order for it to overwrite the first selector when you are hovering over the element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksq2LsbL/)

```
#map figure:hover {
    clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 0px);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

For what it's worth, here is the [specificity calculation](http://specificity.keegan.st/) of each selector:

- `#map figure` - 101
- `figure:hover` - 11
- `#map figure:hover` - 111

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I didn't notice that.